# Combinatorial process on multisets of integers

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, combinatorial-optimization, extremal-graph-theory

***Edit:*** *I prefer to formulate first the problem as Fedor Petrov suggests in the comments*:

We are given a multiset $F$, initially containing only the single integer $h$. Sequentially, at each time step, one of the currently maximal elements $t$ of $F$ is replaced by $0, 1, 2, \ldots, t-1$. The process ends when all elements of $F$ are equal to $0$.

---

**Question:** Given any integer $1\le k\le h$, what is the number $n(k,h)$ of elements eliminated that are equal to $k$?

Comment: what if the longest path is not unique?

Comment: Thank you @FedorPetrov for your question. By the symmetry of $T$ I think that the result does not change. I am adding now that the selected path is *arbitrary*. Thanks.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I think now is clearer. Please, correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: It is symmetric on the first step, the intermediate trees seem to be rather non-symmetric.

Comment: But then $n(k, h) $ depends not only on $k, h$, but also on the process.

Comment: I think it is symmetric @FedorPetrov because you can always represent each tree in $F$ in such a way that the longest paths are "on the left" in an decreasing order from left to right. It's just a matter of "rotate" some of the subtrees.

Comment: @FedorPetrov perhaps I am wrong, but I think that up to homomorphism you always work on the same structure. Note that each tree in $F$ must be always full perfect (like the initial one).

Comment: ah, I see, they are all again full perfect binary trees of heights $h-1,h-2,\ldots,1$. So, the question may be repharsed as: you have a multiset of numbers, initially it contains the single element $h$, and on each step each element $t$ is replaced to $1,2,\ldots,t-1$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you @FedorPetrov . I like this compact form. At each step, one of the *maximal* element $t$ is replaced to $1, 2, \ldots, t-1$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov I added your formulation. Thanks-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I claim that $n(k,h)=1$ when $k\in \{h,h-1\}$ and $n(k,h)=2^{h-k-1}$ otherwise (if $k<h-1$).
Proof by induction. For $h=1$ this is clear. Induction step. Assume that for smaller values of $h$ this holds. For $k\in \{h-1,h\}$ this is clear. So assume that $k<h-1$. We have $n(k,h)=n(k,h-1)+n(k,h-2)+\ldots$. Thus the claim follows from the identity $2^m=1+1+2+2^2+\ldots+2^{m-1}$, where $m=h-k-1$.

Comment: The same result can be "seen" as follows (though ultimately the proof is essentially the same). For any $k<h$, any occurrence of $k$ during the process arose from the elimination of some larger $t$, which, if it isn't $h$, arose from the elimination of a still larger $t'$, etc.  This sequence of "ancestors" $t,t',\dots$ of $k$ ends at $h$, and the other terms of the sequence form an arbitrary subset of the interval $[k+1,h-1]$.  There are $2^{h-k-1}$ such subsets.